# Correct way to check for a command line flag in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, flags

In the middle of a script, I want to check if a given flag was passed on the command line. The following does what I want but seems ugly:

```
if echo $* | grep -e "--flag" -q
then
  echo ">>>> Running with flag"
else
  echo ">>>> Running without flag"
fi
```

*Is there a better way?*

Note: I explicitly *don't* want to list all the flags in a switch/getopt. (In this case any such things would become half or more of the full script. Also the bodies of the if just set a set of vars)

Answer (score 91):

An alternative to what you're doing:

```
if [[ $* == *--flag* ]]
```

See also [BashFAQ/035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).

> **Note**: This will also match `--flags-off` since it's a simple substring check.

Comment: Won't that also pick up false positives? e.g. if you chech for `*-f*` it will match `--force`, `-fish`, `--update-files`, `-w-t-f`etc

Comment: @nathanchere: careful choice of match string is important. Note that your example allows for all the matches that you list but mine leaves much fewer possibilities of false positives. Given the OP's requirement for a simple solution mine fits quite well. Otherwise use getopt or getopts.

Comment: Exactly my point. Mine was an intentionally simplified example, but still demonstrates the same issue with yours. e.g. if you use `*--flag*` you will match `--flag`, `--flags-off` etc. i.e. it's a sloppy solution

Comment: @nathanchere You're welcome to post a better solution that meets the OP's requirements.

Comment: Could you please tell how to get the ordinal of that `$*`?

Comment: @OptimusPrime: Why do you want the ordinal?

Comment: Let's say the flag is at 5th position, then $6 would give me its value.

Comment: @OptimusPrime: The OP wanted a quick and dirty way to check for a flag without using `getopt`. For complete processing of flags with (and/or without) arguments, you should use techniques as described in the FAQ I linked to.

Comment: Is there no need for `"$*"`?

Comment: @Randoms: If you're asking whether there's a need for quoting - it's not necessary inside double square brackets.

Comment: My small [modification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65811916/8854890) that solves the mentioned problem of the false positives

Comment: This does not work in Bash at all...

Comment: @Cerin: Yes it does, but "does not work" conveys no information at all. What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson My mistake. Your solution only works in the top-level scope, where I was trying to use it inside a function, which of course redefines `$*`. Storing the top level arguments to a variable made it work for my case.

Answer (score 21):

I typically see this done with a case statement.  Here's an excerpt from the [git-repack](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-repack.html) script:

```
while test $# != 0
do
    case "$1" in
    -n) no_update_info=t ;;
    -a) all_into_one=t ;;
    -A) all_into_one=t
        unpack_unreachable=--unpack-unreachable ;;
    -d) remove_redundant=t ;;
    -q) GIT_QUIET=t ;;
    -f) no_reuse=--no-reuse-object ;;
    -l) local=--local ;;
    --max-pack-size|--window|--window-memory|--depth)
        extra="$extra $1=$2"; shift ;;
    --) shift; break;;
    *)  usage ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Note that this allows you to check for both short and long flags.  Other options are built up using the `extra` variable in this case.

Comment: I think you have to remove the last 'shift' statement, right after the 'esac'. At least on my machine it doesn't work if it's present.

Comment: @ThomasKrille The shift at the end is necessary to move onto the next argument. If you remove it, it would run infinitely (unless you're using one of the options that have shift in the case).

Answer (score 15):

you can take the straight-forward approach, and iterate over the arguments to test each of them for equality with a given parameter (e.g. `-t`, `--therizinosaurus`).

put it into a function:

```bash
has_param() {
    local term="$1"
    shift
    for arg; do
        if [[ $arg == "$term" ]]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}
```

… and use it as a predicate in test expressions:

```bash
if has_param '-t' "$@"; then
    echo "yay!"
fi

if ! has_param '-t' "$1" "$2" "$wat"; then
    echo "nay..."
fi
```

if you want to reject empty arguments, add an exit point at the top of the loop body:

```bash
for arg; do
    if [[ -z "$arg" ]]; then
        return 2
    fi
    # ...
```

this is very *readable*, and will not give you false positives, like pattern matching or regex matching will.
it will also allow placing flags at arbitrary positions, for example, you can put `-h` at the end of the command line (not going into whether it's good or bad).

---

*but*, the more i thought about it, the more something bothered me.

with a function, you can take any implementation (e.g. `getopts`), and reuse it. encapsulation rulez!
but even with commands, this strength can become a flaw. if you'll be using it again and again, you'll be parsing all the arguments each time.

my tendency is to favor reuse, but i have to be aware of the implications. the opposed approach would be to parse these arguments once at the script top, as you dreaded, and avoid the repeated parsing.
you can still encapsulate that switch case, which can be as big as you decide (you don't have to list *all* the options).

Comment: This was the best answer!

Comment: great answer. Note this can also be used for multiple parameters. i found this cleaner then getopts as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the getopt keyword in bash.

From http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html:

> getopt
>
> This is a standalone executable that has been around a long time.
>   Older versions lack the ability to handle quoted arguments (foo a "this
>   won't work" c) and the versions that can, do so clumsily. If you are
>   running a recent Linux version, your "getopt" can do that; SCO OSR5,
>   Mac OS X 10.2.6 and FreeBSD 4.4 has an older version that does not.
>
> The simple use of "getopt" is shown in this mini-script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Before getopt"
for i
do
  echo $i
done
args=`getopt abc:d $*`
set -- $args
echo "After getopt"
for i
do
  echo "-->$i"
done
```

Comment: It's better to use the builtin `getopts` rather than the external `getopt`.

Comment: @Dennis:  `getopts` supports long option names like `--flag`?

Comment: @indiv: Oh, sorry, I overlooked that requirement. I would use a `case` statement before I would use `getopt`. See [this](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html) for a comparison of `getopt` and `getopts`.

Comment: From the faq in the above answer:

getopts:

Unless it's the version from util-linux, and you use its advanced mode, never use getopt(1). Traditional versions of getopt cannot handle empty argument strings, or arguments with embedded whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

I've made small changes to the answer of [Eliran Malka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56431189/313501):

This function can evaluate different parameter synonyms, like "-q" and "--quick". Also, it does not use return 0/1 but an echo to return a non-null value when the parameter is found:

```
function has_param() {
    local terms="$1"
    shift

    for term in $terms; do
        for arg; do
            if [[ $arg == "$term" ]]; then
                echo "yes"
            fi
        done
    done
}

# Same usage:

# Assign result to a variable.
FLAG_QUICK=$(has_param "-q --quick" "$@")  # "yes" or ""

# Test in a condition using the nonzero-length-test to detect "yes" response.
if [[ -n $(has_param "-h --help" "$@") ]]; then; 
    echo "Need help?"
fi

# Check, is a flag is NOT set by using the zero-length test.
if [[ -z $(has_param "-f --flag" "$@") ]]; then
    echo "FLAG NOT SET"
fi
```

Comment: nice! piping the data back as output is an awesome addition - it streamlines the command api greatly, and adding the ability to check a list of terms is also quite cool (though the external loop will further strain on performance..). <3

Comment: meta - sometimes stackoverflow is a bit like github. should we add that `SO fork` feature already and be done with it? :D

Comment: Note, if your doing the check inside a function, you can't use "$@", because that will refer to the function's arguments. You'd need to cache the script's arguments in a global variable.

Answer (score 4):

The modification of [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876177/8854890) with additional example for a argument in the short form.

```sh
if [[ \ $*\  == *\ --flag\ * ]] || [[ \ $*\  == *\ -f\ * ]]
```

It solves the problem of false positive matching `--flags-off` and even `--another--flag` (more popular such case for an one-dashed arguments: `--one-more-flag` for `*-f*`).

`\` (backslash + space) means space for expressions inside `[[ ]]`. Putting spaces around `$*` allows to be sure that the arguments contacts neither line's start nor line's end, they contacts only spaces. And now the target flag surrounded by spaces can be searched in the line with arguments.

Answer (score 4):

```
if [ "$1" == "-n" ]; then
    echo "Flag set";
fi
```

Comment: this will only work if the flag was the first argument passed in the command.

Comment: And this will fail if the flag is not set and you have `set -u`, which you want

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation on the most voted answer that **won't** pick up false positives

```
if [[ " $* " == *" -r "* ]]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

One more variation:

```bash
flag1="false"
if [[ " $@ " =~ " --flag1 " ]]; then
    flag1="true"
fi

flag2="false"
if [[ " $@ " =~ " --flag2 " ]]; then
    flag2="true"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Mb something like:

```bash
if [[ ($* == -f) || ($* == --flag) ]];
then
  echo ">>>> Running with flag"
else
  echo ">>>> Running without flag"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Not an alternative, but an improvement, though.

```
if echo $* | grep -e "\b--flag\b" -q
```

Looking for [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) will make sure to really get the option `--flag` and neither `--flagstaff` nor `--not-really--flag`

Comment: This will not work.
E.g. `echo '--foo-bar' | grep -e "--foo\b"` fails.
See explanation of why [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)